# Attach files from inbound emails to multiple records

Tags: apex, attachment, apex-email-service, emailfileattachment, inboundemail

We are using email service and apex class to create records on a custom object whenever an email is received. If the email contains an attachment, it is attached to the 'Notes & Attachment' under the custom object related list, but when a user opens the EmailMessage record, they cannot see the attachment there. Is it possible to attach the files from the inbound email to both the custom object and EmailMessage object?

Here is the apex class:

```
public class TT_CaseEmailService implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

    public Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, 
                                                           Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) 
    {
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();   
        Custom_Object__c ttCase = new Custom_Object__c();

        if(email.references == null){
            ttCase = createTTCase(email);
        } 
        
        if (ttCase.Id != null) {
            createTTEmailMessage(ttCase.Id, email);
        }
            
        if(email.textAttachments != null && ttCase.Id != null) {
            createTextAttachment(ttCase.Id, email);
        }
        
        if(email.binaryAttachments != null && ttCase.Id != null){
            createBinaryAttachment(ttCase.Id, email);
        }
       
        return result;
   }
    
    @testVisible  
    private static Custom_Object__c createTTCase(Messaging.InboundEmail inboundMessage){

        Custom_Object__c tt = new Custom_Object__c();
        
        try {
            tt.Sender_Email__c = inboundMessage.fromAddress;
            tt.Sender_Name__c = inboundMessage.fromName;
            tt.Subject__c = String.isNotBlank(inboundMessage.subject) ? inboundMessage.subject : 'No Subject';
     
            insert tt;
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('The following exception has occurred on createTTCase : ' + e.getMessage());
        }
        
        return tt;
   }

    
    @testVisible
    private static void createTextAttachment(String parentRecordId, Messaging.InboundEmail emailMessage){
        List<Attachment> textAttachemntList = new List<Attachment>();
        
        try {
            for (Messaging.Inboundemail.TextAttachment tAttachment : emailMessage.textAttachments) {
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
                attachment.Name = tAttachment.fileName;
                attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(tAttachment.body);
                attachment.ParentId = parentRecordId;
                textAttachemntList.add(attachment);
            }
            
            if(textAttachemntList.size()>0){
                insert textAttachemntList;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            system.debug('Exception occurred on createTextAttachment : ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    @testVisible
    private static void createBinaryAttachment(String parentRecordId, Messaging.InboundEmail emailMessage) {
        List<Attachment> binaryAttachment = new List<Attachment>();
        try {
            for (Messaging.Inboundemail.BinaryAttachment bAttachment : emailMessage.binaryAttachments) {
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
                attachment.Name = bAttachment.fileName;
                attachment.Body = bAttachment.body;
                attachment.ParentId = parentRecordId;
                binaryAttachment.add(attachment);
            }
        
            if(binaryAttachment.size()>0){
                insert binaryAttachment;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            system.debug('Exception occurred on createBinaryAttachment : ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
   
    @testVisible
    private static void createTTEmailMessage(String ttCaseId, Messaging.InboundEmail email) {

        EmailMessage em = new EmailMessage();
        try {

            em.HtmlBody = email.htmlBody;
            em.TextBody = email.plainTextBody;
            em.Incoming = true;
            em.Status = '1';
            em.ToAddress = (email.ToAddresses == null || email.ToAddresses.isEmpty()) ? '' : String.join(email.ToAddresses, ',');
            em.FromAddress = email.fromAddress;
            em.FromName = email.fromName;
            em.RelatedToId = ttCaseId;
            em.CcAddress = (email.ccAddresses == null || email.ccAddresses.isEmpty()) ? '' : String.join(email.ccAddresses, ',');
            em.Subject = String.isNotBlank(email.subject) ? email.Subject : 'No Subject';
        
            insert em;
                    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            system.debug('Exception occurred on createTTEmailMessage : ' + e.getMessage());
        }
   }
    
}
```